# SSIS Transfer to Oracle linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

In our SQL Server 2016 Standard, we have a linked server to an Oracle database.

For example, we have linked server `SERVERINT..SCHEMA.TABLE`

```
SELECT * 
FROM SERVERINT..SCHEMA.TABLE
```

returns the data.

For simplicity we have created a synonym, for example `DBO.TABLE`.

But we do not know how we set SSIS transfer and Data Flow transfer with synonym. Synonym is destination.

In `OLE_DB_DESTINATION` we can see table `dbo.table` and we set here.
But in during transfer we get error:

> The object dbo.table does not exists

Are we able to set destination to synonym or table in linked server?

Answer (score 1):

Most client tools with a "table picker" don't understand synonyms.  Use Table or View Name From Variable, or provide a custom SQL command.

However you should really not insert SSIS > SQL Server > Linked Server > Oracle.  Instead insert from SSIS directly to Oracle.  If you have a Linked Server to Oracle you already have the Oracle OleDb provider installed and working on the SQL Server.